# All vuetify selects look like they are selected

Tags: vue.js, select, vuetify.js, v-select

Why are all select items blue in this example? It looks like they are already selected.

```
<v-select
    v-model="obj"
    :items="arrOfObj"
>
    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
        Obj: {{data.item.a}}
    </template>
    <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
        Obj: {{data.item.a}}
    </template>
</v-select>
```

```
let arrOfObj = [{a: 1},{a: 2},{a: 3}]

export default {
    data: () => ({
        arrOfObj: arrOfObj,
        obj: {a: 2}
    })
}
```

I have prepared a **codepen** for this: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Tenarius/pen/bGpqEEj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    arrOfObj: [{
      a: 1
    }, {
      a: 2
    }, {
      a: 3
    }],
    obj: 2
  })
})
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.2.2/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.2.2/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-select v-model="obj" :items="arrOfObj" item-text="a" item-value="a">
          <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
                                Obj: {{data.item.a}}
                            </template>
          <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
                                Obj: {{data.item.a}}
                            </template>
        </v-select>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

You can specify the specific properties within your items array correspond to the `text` and `value` fields. By default, this is `text` and `value`.

If you want the type of `obj` to be an object, also can use the `return-object` prop which will return the entire object of the selected item on selection.

```html
<v-select v-model="obj" :items="arrOfObj" item-text="a" item-value="a" return-object>
```

```js
data: () => ({
    obj: {a:2}
  })
```